# Firefox not allowing fullscreen from iFrame

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, youtube-api

I am fairly savvy with HTML but no expert. We have a website which we are embedding a YouTube video in. Every other browser (including mobile) allows the video to be put in full-screen but Firefox doesn't. I was reading the Mozilla Developers site on it but it's all Greek to me. Help would be appreciated, here is the code sample:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M3NSa_-7fbM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you testing your `<iframe>` on JSfiddle or W3schools? Full-screen is only allowed if the `<iframe>` is not in another `<iframe>`. You also need to allow full-screen on YouTube by clicking the full-screen icon and then "allow."

Comment: Testing it live, and if I click full screen on YouTube in Firefox it does nothing, other browsers are fine

Comment: Have you denied access to full-screen before?

Comment: I tested it from another computer in Firefox and it works.  You may be right, I may have blocked it before.  Thanks!